# ValueError: time data on Python

Tags: python

Good morning. Recently I started to develop an application using QT. But I had some trouble with it. In fact, there is a very strange error with time data, and it only comes up if I try to execute it with the GUI, not via CLI.

This is the error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Wed Nov  4 09:10:14 2020' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
```

Comment: There is an extra space between `Nov` & `4` in the input string

Comment: The extra space is fine, though.

Comment: My guess would be that the GUI adds some sort of special character which is either invisible (perhaps BOM) or looks like a space (perhaps non-breaking space), especially if the time is cut and pasted from some other application. Try logging or printing out the failing string more carefully, perhaps with `date_str.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')`, to see if there's something unexpected in there?

Comment: The extra space between Nov & 4 comes from the modification time of a file. I've tried to calling the 'def' from another script and it works. I don't understand why it won't to work if I call it from the GUI, same, the GUI doesn't interfere.

Answer (score 0):

I probably need more information like how you actually wrote the code.

The brief idea is :

'09/11/2020 12:39:20' matches with '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

'Wed Nov 4 09:10:14 2020' matches with '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'

or you can also try
DATETIMEPARSE([Subscription End],'%b %d %Y')